# How can I grouping an unix time per day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// requests
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | id_user  |  unix_time  |
+----+----------+-------------+
| 1  | 2353     | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 2353     | 1339412864  |
| 3  | 5462     | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422     | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 3422     | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 2353     | 1339412906  |
| 7  | 7785     | 1339412951  |
| 8  | 2353     | 1339413640  |
| 9  | 5462     | 1339413621  |
| 10 | 5462     | 1339414490  |
| 11 | 2353     | 1339414923  |
| 12 | 2353     | 1339419901  |
| 13 | 8007     | 1339424860  |
| 14 | 7785     | 1339424822  |
| 15 | 2353     | 1339424902  |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

I want to grouping `unix_time` column based on separated days. Actually I'm trying to make this for an specific user:

[image]

As you see I need tow numbers for an user:

- the number of all days which there is a foot print of the user into `requests` table
- the number of biggest consecutive days

How can I do that?

Actually I can use `WHERE id_user = :id` to select user's rows. And I can calculate the number of days by `SUM()`. And by using `MAX()` I can calculate the biggest consecutive range. Just I need to grouping those unix times.

Comment: I believe this is a standard gaps and islands problem, which could be slightly tricky given that you are using MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well what's the problem here? That unix-time or using MySQL ?

Comment: No...your question is a "gaps and islands" problem, Google gaps and islands to get a hint about how to solve this.

Comment: For the same user , same day multiple records exist in your `requests` table?

Comment: @1000111 Absolutely yes. That table contains all requests. A request happens when user opens a page of my website. So an user can send multiple requests as the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT 
t.id_user,
COUNT(*) totalVisits,
MAX(t.max_cons) maxCons
FROM 
(SELECT
        id_user,
        @lastUnixTime AS lastUnixTimeOfuser,
        IF(@uid <> id_user, @currentMax := 1 , @currentMax),
        IF(@uid <> id_user, @lastUnixTime := 0, @lastUnixTime := @lastUnixTimeOfLastRecord),

        IF(@uid = id_user, 
                    IF((@lastUnixTime + 86400) >= utime, @currentMax := @currentMax + 1, @currentMax := 1), @lastUnixTime := 0),
        IF(@currentMax > @max, @max := @currentMax, @max ),
        IF(@uid <> id_user , @max := 1 ,@max),
        @uid := id_user,    
        @lastUnixTimeOfLastRecord := utime,
        @max AS max_cons
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            id_user,
            (unix_time DIV 86400) * 86400 AS utime
        FROM requests 
        GROUP BY id_user, utime ) dayWiseRequestTable ,
        (
            SELECT
                @uid := 0,
                @currentMax := 0,
                @max := 0,
                @lastUnixTime := 0,
                @lastUnixTimeOfLastRecord := 0
        ) vars

    ORDER BY id_user, utime) t
GROUP BY t.id_user;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad035/13/0)

**Output:**

The final output looks like below:

```
id_user Total_Visits    Maximum_Consecutive_Visits
2353        7                    2
3422        2                    2
5462        3                    2
7785        2                    1
8007        1                    1
```

**EDIT:**

In order to get output for a specific user you need to add a `WHERE clause in the inner query`.

Please check this

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad035/6/0)

Comment: Seems correct. thx +1 ..! Just may you please tell me how can I do that for one specific user? I mean should I add this `WHERE id_user = :id` in the which part of your query?

Comment: You need to put the where clause like this: `....FROM requests
        WHERE id_user = 5462....` . Please check the latest fiddle under the **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: I see, thx, just I think if I want to select rows for specific users, then this is redundant `GROUP BY utime`, Am I right?

Comment: No, `For the particular user` case the last group by is redundant. **This one** `GROUP BY t.id_user;` By the way, `GROUP BY utime` groups the data in daily basis of a user.

Comment: Tried to add another fiddle.But failed. Look at this [**query**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17593987/). A slightly different approach in grouping by `date`. @Shafizadeh

Comment: What you linked [works as well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad035/8), Why did you say you failed?

Comment: I failed to add a fiddle of this query http://paste.ubuntu.com/17593987/

Comment: Ah got it .. `:-)` ..! Thanks for your attention. Actually I'm waiting for Gordon to edit his answer, otherwise I'll mark your answer as accepted one.

Comment: Here you can find `Gordon's` answer running. Here you can find that http://paste.ubuntu.com/17595131/.  But I cannot guarantee whether it's giving expected result or not.

Comment: Sorry to ping you again, just can you please tell me is that possible to I also add one more column to the result named `lastCons` which is containing the number of last consecutive days?

Comment: I think this is not easy to introduce that calculation in this query. I will definitely think about it.But I can assure that it will be cumbersome to do that

Answer (score 2):

Use can extract the day using `from_unixtime()`.  Then you can get count the days using variables:

```
select id_user, d,
       (@rn := if(@di = concat_ws(':', d - interval 1 day, id_user), @rn + 1,
                  if(@di :=  concat_ws(':', d, id_user), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rn
from (select id_user, date(from_unixtime(unix_time)) as d
      from t
      group by id_user, d
     ) cross join
     (select @di := '', @rn := 0) params
order by id_user, d;
```

From here to the summary is just an aggregation:

```
select id_user, count(*) as numdays, max(rn) as maxconsecutive
from (select id_user, d,
             (@rn := if(@di = concat_ws(':', d - interval 1 day, id_user), @rn + 1,
                        if(@di :=  concat_ws(':', d, id_user), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select id_user, date(from_unixtime(unix_time)) as d
            from t
            group by id_user, d
           ) cross join
           (select @di := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by id_user, d
     ) ud
group by id_user;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a67a/8) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating the code.

Comment: Odd .. The first non-working answer form Gordon I've seen here so far.

Comment: @stack . . . It is now fixed, at least how I interpret the question.

Comment: Thx for the edit .. Yeah it woks now, +1 ..! Just as a note, is that possible to I also add one more column to the result named *LastConsecutive* which is containing the number of last consecutive days?

Comment: @Shafizadeh . . . You should ask that as another question.